# method to create an android free messaging app

Tags: c#, android, html, asp.net

I want to create an android application to send sms to another number free of cost using the intenet.
Is there any api present for that or is there any other approach.

The method i want to use is:-
1.I want to create an interface which will accept the text and the number to send the text(the general user interface to send any message).
2.I want to send the message and the number(both receiver and sender) to a aspx page present in the server.
3.The server accepts the number (both receiver and sender)and store it in a database.(optional)
4.The aspx page then sends the message to the receiver's phone number and also shows the sender's phone number.
5.The aspx page can have an option of registering and authenticating the user for the particular android app.(optional)

Is this approach applicable or if there is any other approach please do let me know.
Please provide some links/sample codes for the tutorial purpose
Thank You for any help provided..

Answer (score 0):

You can give a look on http://programmableweb.com/ for a directory of public API.

For SMS API specifically, you can get a list here: http://www.programmableweb.com/apitag/?q=SMS

Regards!